# Onclick event to move an element down a specific number of pixels

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know some things about HTML and CSS but I want to build code that will move an element a certain amount of pixels after a click, and then return it after another click.

The two websites that I have are these:
http://www.miguelonenterprises.com/2018roadtrip.htm
http://www.miguelonenterprises.com/wrap6.css.

Right now I have it set to a hover property.

I found this site which potentially has the answers:http://jsfiddle.net/fgvr2/][1](http://jsfiddle.net/fgvr2/)

```
$(function(){
    $('.box').on('click',function(){
       $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    });
});
```

And I can integrate the CSS and HTML just fine. But I have no idea how to integrate the JavaScript / JQuery element.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: you can use Javascript code between the `<script>` & `</script>` tags in the `<head> </head>` section of your page

Comment: Also the source code of the `2018roadtip.htm` needs to be corrected semantically.

Answer (score 1):

You can `toggle` a class when the `element` is clicked which would place the `element` a specific number of pixels lower. You also need to add a `transition-duration` for the property that should start a transition when changed (in this case `top`).

```js
$(function(){
    $('.movingBox').on('click',function(){
       $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    });
});
```

```css
.movingBox{
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid red;
  top: 10px;
  transition: top 1s;
}

.clicked{
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;/*whatever number of pixels you want the div to be from the top of the page*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="movingBox">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you’ve set the CSS position property to `absolute`, it can be done very easily in JavaScript without jquery. Let’s say that the HTML ID of your element is `example`. 
In JavaScript you can do the following:

```
var element = document.querySelector(“example”);
element.addEventListener(“click”,function () {
    var temp = element.style.top.substring(0,element.style.top.length - 2);
    element.style.top = (parseInt(temp) + 5 ) + “px”;
}
```

From the code it should be clear how to return it to it’s original position after the click. If it isn’t I encourage that you learn some JavaScript [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jS/default.asp).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it. Toggle a `class` and add `transition-duration` to the moving element.

```js
/* Copy this content to a js file. Example "click.js" */

$('.myWrapper').on('click', () => {
  $('.myMover').toggleClass('addMargin');
});
```

```css
/* Copy this content to a css file. Example click_style.css */    

.myWrapper {
  width: 100px;
}

.myText {
  background-color: #FF9800;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.myMover {
  transition-duration: 1s;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #FF9800;
}

.addMargin {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Load the css and js from files (place in <head></head> of your html-file)-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="click.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="click_style.css" />

<div class="myWrapper">
  <div class="myText">
    Some Text
  </div>
  <div class="myMover">
    I'm moving!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good examples. However, one thing I don't like are in-line entries. I like to keep things separate and clean. Can any of you provide CSS file examples for the styles presented in the HTML?

Comment: What do you mean by __in-line entries__ ? Anything i forgot to move to the right place? Help me I dont see it.

Comment: Pilan your example is the best I've seen so far. However, the CSS style as well as the JavaScript is on the same page as the HTML. That's what is meant by in-line. I can convert the style to a .css file no problem. What changes need to be made so that the JavaScript is saved to a separate .js file? Is it even possible? There is a good chance that I'll run with your example in its current form.

Comment: @MichaelLopez Oh you are new to stackoverflow. I'll explain. The Code you see in 3 grey boxes IS seperated. Place each grey`s box content to a file. (I edit the code so you know what to do.)